# jQuery global var isn't working

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to declare global variable but it keeps saying `undefined`.

```
<div class="last">Blah</div>
```

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(document).on('click', '.last', function() {
        window.testing = $(this).html();
    })
    console.log(testing);
})
```

I tried this too.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var testing;
    $(document).on('click', '.last', function() {
        testing = $(this).html();
    })
    console.log(testing);
})
```

Comment: Your code works fine, but not how you are expecting it to. You read the  `testing` variable on load of the DOM, yet you only give it a value *after* clicking the button. Also note that using global variables is not a good thing to be doing. If you need to allow variables to be used in various places, use a namespace.

Comment: set `var testing` before the document ready function and it will run as a global variable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code works fine, but not how you are expecting it to. You read the  `testing` variable on load of the DOM, yet you only give it a value *after* clicking the button. Instead you need a way to read the `window.testing` variable after it has been set. Here's an example using a button click.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(document).on('click', '.last', function() {
    window.testing = $(this).html();
  })

  $('button').click(function() {
    console.log(window.testing);
  });
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="last">Set</div>
<button>Read</button>
```

Also note that using global variables is not a good thing to be doing. If you need to allow variables to be used in various places, use a namespace.

Comment: Hey Thanks for explaining  , your code is working . But i am still confused why do i have to use click button function to get the value? why i cant i get the value directly by using console.log
Thanks

Comment: It's because your original console.log runs as soon as the page loads. At that time the value is not set. You then click the button, say 5 seconds after the page has loaded and there is no more code which reads the value of the variable. Hence I added a new button which you can then click at any time to read that value.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```js
$(function() {
 
  var testing;

  $('.last').click(function() {

    testing = $(this).html();

    alert(testing);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="last">Blah (click here)</div>
```

Your code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var testing; // testing = undefined

    $(document).on('click', '.last', function() {

        testing = $(this).html();
    })

    console.log(testing); // prints undefined, because onlick event has not fired yet and testing is not equal to $(this).html();
}
```

Comment: You are using testing variable inside the function. I Want it to be used outside the function & also I need the  value of element "last" when user clicks on it .

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
var testing = "";
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(document).on('click', '.last', function() {
        testing = $(this).html();
    });
    console.log(testing);
});
```

## Edited

Try passing simple value to the variable and then your .last class value

```
var testing = "";
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(document).click(function() {
        testing = 1;
        alert(testing);
    });

});
```